# Get folder on in same directory as App domain path

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net web app and i need to get the string path of a folder in the same directory as my web app. 
Currently im using this code to get the add domain path.

```
string appPath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath;
```

Which returns "c:/path/webapp", i need "c:/path/folder".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like a more generic approach that doesn't require knowing the starting folder:

```
//NOTE:  using System.IO;
String startPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath);
Int32 pos = startPath.LastIndexOf(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
String newPath = Path.Combine(startPath.Substring(0, pos), "folder");  //replace "folder" if it's really something else, of course
```

This way, whatever directory your web app is running from, you can get it, reduce it by one level, and tack on "folder" to get your new sibling directory.

Comment: If i had to use a class library in my webb app. And in the class library i had to get the webb app domain path. How would i achieve this.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the class library will be running in a context that doesn't know about the web app?  Do you need an alternative to `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath`?

Comment: Yes i do . It will reside in a class library.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I need an alternative to `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath`. Did you have something in mind?

Comment: @ShawnSouth Off the top of my head:  System.AppDomain.BaseDirectory or HttpContext.Current?

Comment: @DonBoitnott Thanks. Those are the only other options I'm aware of as well. Problem is I can't be guaranteed to always have `HttpContext` or that the current `AppDomain` is the one I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) method.

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in
>   the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

```
string appPath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath;
appPath = appPath.Replace("webapp", "folder");
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/bj2T70).

Thanks to DonBoitnott comments, here is the right answer;

```
string appPath = @"C:\mydir\anotherdir\webapp\thirddir\webapp";
int LastIndex = appPath.LastIndexOf("webapp", StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
string RealappPath = Path.Combine(appPath.Substring(0, LastIndex), "folder");
Console.WriteLine(RealappPath);
```

This will print;

```
C:\mydir\anotherdir\webapp\thirddir\folder
```

Comment: what if there is a folder with the same name along the path, that too will change.

Comment: @StylesYoung What do you mean change? What is your purpose?

Comment: I think he means you take it too literally...that path might not always literally be "C:\path\webapp"....it could be "C:\mydir\anotherdir\webapp\thirddir\webapp".  In your solution, that path is wrecked by String.Replace().

Comment: @DonBoitnott So if it is `"C:\mydir\anotherdir\webapp\thirddir\webapp"` OP doesn't want the result as `"C:\mydir\anotherdir\folder\thirddir\folder"` ? Or still want `c:/path/folder` ?

Comment: @SonerGönül If the app path is "C:\mydir\anotherdir\webapp\thirddir\webapp", the OP wants the folder path to be "C:\mydir\anotherdir\webapp\thirddir\folder".

Comment: @DonBoitnott So, the patters is always replace last `webapp` with `folder` ? Is it only required?

Comment: @SonerGönül Here's the critical part of the question:  `"i need to get the string path of a folder in the same directory as my web app"`.  Same folder as my web app.  If web app = `"C:\mydir\anotherdir\webapp\thirddir\webapp"` then web app folder = `"C:\mydir\anotherdir\webapp\thirddir\"`, thus same folder as web app = `"C:\mydir\anotherdir\webapp\thirddir\folder"`.  By definition `"C:\mydir\anotherdir\folder\thirddir\folder"` is NOT in the same folder as `"C:\mydir\anotherdir\webapp\thirddir\webapp"`.